# PHP file_get_contents gives HTTP code 401 Unauthorized

Tags: php, file-get-contents, http-status-code-401

I try to make an authenticated HTTP GET request but I get a 401 HTTP error. I am sure that the signature is right. Because of that, I think the problem is in the multiple headers on line 18. But I can't find the exact problem unfortunately.

> Warning: file_get_contents(http://test.com/path): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized in /home/host/path.php on line 22

```
<?php
$apiKey = '1';
$apiSecret = '2';

$verb = 'GET';

$path = '/path';
$nonce = '1';
$data = '';

$signature = hash_hmac('sha256', $verb . $path . $nonce . $data, $apiSecret);

$url="http://test.com/path"; 

$opts = [
    "http" => [
        "method" => $verb,
        "header" => "api-nonce: ".$nonce. "\r\n", "api-key: " .$apiKey. "\r\n", "api-signature: " . $signature
    ]
];
$context = stream_context_create($opts);
$json = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);

if($json){
    $data = @json_decode($json, TRUE);

    print_r($data);
}
?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You had a wrong format on line 18.
You used commas to seperate the headers, instead you should just concatenate them as one string:

```
"header" => "api-nonce: ".$nonce. "\r\n" . "api-key: " .$apiKey. "\r\n" . "api-signature: " . $signature . "\r\n"
```

Comment: Thanks! Works perfectly now.